# How custom parse typesafe configuration?

Tags: scala, configuration, akka, typesafe

I want to pass seed node to akka application. For now I have to set java options like that:

```
-Dakka.cluster.seed-nodes.0="akka.tcp://systemName@127.0.0.1:2551"
-Dakka.cluster.seed-nodes.1="akka.tcp://systemName@127.0.0.2:2551"
```

Is there a wat to use IP address shortcut like that:

```
-Dakka.cluster.seed-nodes.0="127.0.0.1:2551"
-Dakka.cluster.seed-nodes.1="127.0.0.2:2551"
```

Can add for example a custom parse for this property passed from commandline?